how to get `hudson.model.Node` from `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun` by groovy in Jenkins
I'm using groovy script in pipeline build to get the current running nodes information.
My current solution is to get the node info by calling Jenkins.instance.getNode with parameter of env.NODE_NAME :
def currentNode = Jenkins.instance.getNode(env.NODE_NAME)
if ( currentNode instanceof org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave ) {
    println currentNode?.toComputer()?.getContainers()?.collect{ it.image }?.join(', ') ?: ''
}

However, I'm thinking, since the build is running inside the current node, the current node ( class hudson.model.Node ) should be get from currentBuild or currentBuild.rawBuild.
So, I tried with currentBuild.rawBuild.getExecutor().getOwner(), but the class is hudson.model.Hudson$MasterComputer, what I'm looking forward to is class org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave, since the build running inside kubernetes pod:
currentBuild.rawBuild           // class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
            .getExecutor()      // class hudson.model.OneOffExecutor
            .getOwner()         // class hudson.model.Hudson$MasterComputer


I'm chasing alternatives solution, is because of env.NODE_NAME isn't the universal solution, since the workflowRun might getting by following script, and there's no env.NODE_NAME obviously:
Jenkins.instance
       .getItemByFullName( JOB_NAME )
       .getBuildByNumber( BUILD_NUMBER )

Can anyone give me some tips ?

update
the workflowRun.actions list:
println currentBuild.rawBuild
                    .actions
                    .collect { it.getClass() }
                    .join('\n')

// results:
class hudson.model.CauseAction
class hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigBadgeAction
class jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction
class org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildtriggerbadge.BuildTriggerBadgeAction
class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibrariesAction
class com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.builds.CredentialsParameterBinder
class hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData
class io.jenkins.plugins.forensics.git.reference.GitCommitsRecord
class hudson.plugins.ansicolor.action.ColorizedAction
class hudson.plugins.ansicolor.action.ColorizedAction
class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl


You are doing the right thing. The other way to get to the node(s) you are currently running on would be to examine all the WorkspaceAction actions, but it adds complexity and is no more correct than Jenkins.get().getNode(env.NODE_NAME).
Update:
If you are looking at past runs then WorkspaceRunAction is pretty much your only option.
def build = Jenkins.get().getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(BUILD_NUMBER)
def wa = build.getAction(WorkspaceRunAction.class).getActions()
wa.each {
    println "${it.node}: ${it.path}"
}

Empty node means built-in.

I've checked the workflowRun.getActions, and there's no WorkspaceAction ( check my latest update ). can you provide more details on the "complexity` solution ?

here is another question, which if the workflowRun isn't getting from build, but getting from Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName( JOB_NAME ).getBuildByNumber( BUILD_NUMBER ), then we cannot get env.NODE_NAME any more.

Right, added an example to show how WorkspaceRunAction can be used.

thanks! the WorkspaceRunAction works to getting the node name. I want to know whether if there any solution to get hudson.model.Node by workflowRun.getXXX().getXXX() directly ?

Not that I know of. And it's potentially a list of nodes. And it can be empty when you do agent: none.
